# VBA dates collected correctly but output wrongly

Tags: excel, vba

I grab dates from one spreadsheet and output them onto another spreadsheet. After grabbing the date, when I debug.print it is in the correct format. When I output the date, debug.print also displays the correct format. However, the format on the spreadsheet the value has just been sent to, doesnt show the correct format.

I am using:

```
Sheets(SheetName).Cells(RowNum, ColNum).Value = Data
Sheets(SheetName).Cells(RowNum, ColNum).NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
```

**after** I have pasted the value, but the months and days are still switched the wrong way.

Is there something I am doing wrong?? If I right click the cell it thinks it's date is dd/mm/yyyy but instead of 4th Sept it is showing 9th April.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I had to format the cell as "TEXT" to keep the correct format

Answer (score 1):

This might be some trouble with localization:

Try using `NumberFormatLocal`, if DanielCooks tip didn't help ;)

*edit:* erlier it was statet by mister Cook, to check if the given data is correct.

*edit:*

With my german version I have quite some trouble to use `/` as the seperator, that is why i tryied with this code `.NumberFormat ="dd-mm-yyyy;@"` - works fine; I can switch days and month as I like.

*edit:*

With `.NumberFormatLocal = "TT/MM/JJJJ"` I have to use the german shorts for day, month and year, but now I can use `/` as the seperator.

You should experiment a litte bit with some formats strings ;)

Comment: Daniel's tip didnt work :( In excel my locale is set to English(UK)

Comment: My tip didn't help, hopefully yours does :-)

Comment: Didnt help :( The data is correct because debug.print is showing the correct values in VBA editor, they're just not showing in the sheet correctly.

Comment: so debug.print on Data gives you what exactly?

Comment: Posted the "solution"/hack below. Not sure why the problem existed.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to resurrect an old post, however I had a problem with VBA outputting a valid date as US style with the actual date changed for example 1st May changed to 5th Jan. I came upon this post but I didn't find the answer I needed here and now that I have worked it out I thought I would share it:

The key is not to define the variable storing the date as a "date" but as a "double", e.g.

```
Dim ReportDate As Double
ReportDate = Date


Range("E6").Value = ReportDate
```

This works as it outputs the numeric "date value" which excel then formats locally e.g. 41644 gets formatted as "05/01/14" using UK format or "01/05/14" using US format.

Hope this proves useful to other people (probably me when I forget how I solved it in six months time).

Answer (score 0):

(1) You need to define the variable to "Date" type to read the input, then set the date format before assigning it to the date variable.

(2) You also need to format the date output to make it work !

'*****Read the date input*******

```
Dim date1 as Date

Range("B2").NumberFormatLocal = "dd/mm/yyyy"

date1 = Range("B2").Value
```

'*****Output the date*******

```
Range("E2").Value = date1 

Range("E2").NumberFormatLocal = "dd/mm/yyyy"
```